# norm equivalence

Tags: sobolev-spaces

hi i want to prove that  we have:

$N_{1}=\|u\|_{H^{2}(\Omega)}$

and

$N_{2}=\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega})+\|\Delta u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega})$
are equivalent norms
what  i propose is :
$\|u\|_{H^{2}(\Omega)} \sim |u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+ \sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=2}|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} $ where $\lvert\alpha\rvert=2$
and $\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=2}|D^{\alpha}u\|_{l^{2}(\Omega)} \le |\Delta u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} $where $\lvert\alpha\rvert=2$

so we concluse that $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ are equivalent norms
my proof is correct?
noting that $\Omega$ is bounded regular domain , here $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$

thank you